# Cast as Int only when character is a number on Firebird 2.5

Tags: sql-order-by, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a query that I use on a MySQL database that orders the result, casting a char database field to integer when possible (when the char string is numeric), so for example the `ORDER BY` clause that I use on MySQL is:

```
ORDER BY
   CASE 
   WHEN CONVERT(charfield, SIGNED INTEGER) IS NOT NULL THEN
        CAST(charfield AS SIGNED INTEGER)  
   ELSE 9999999999 END
```

Where charfield is a database field character(25).

How can I translate this `ORDER BY` clause for Firebird 2.5?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `SIMILAR TO` operator, ie

```
ORDER BY
   CASE 
      WHEN charfield SIMILAR TO '[0-9]+' THEN CAST(charfield AS INTEGER) 
      ELSE 9999999 
   END
```

If the field has leading or trailing spaces then you have to use `TRIM()` function to get rid of those before test, ie

```
WHEN TRIM(charfield) SIMILAR TO ...
```

And to allow negative numbers you have to modify the pattern to include `-`, ie the clause would became

```
ORDER BY
   CASE 
      WHEN TRIM(charfield) SIMILAR TO '\-?[0-9]+' ESCAPE '\' THEN CAST(charfield AS INTEGER) 
      ELSE 9999999 
   END
```