# SQL Convert character to numeric

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a have a column which is set as character but users can insert numbers.

How can I identify when the field has numbers length 11 and not letters?

Example:

sample data `{col1= aaaaaaaaaaa,11111122222}`

```
select Col1
from
table
group by 1
having SUM(CHARACTER_LENGTH(Col1))=11
```

wrong output: `aaaaaaaaaa`

desired output: `11111122222`

In short, I need to retrieve all values in the char column that could be identified as numbers and having 11 digits.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288228/cast-as-int-only-when-character-is-a-number-on-firebird-2-5 Try this solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`similar to`](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-similar-to.html) and [`character_length()`](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-intfunc-char_length.html):

```
select * from tablename
where (col similar to '[0-9]+') and character_length(col) = 11
```

or:

```
select * from tablename
where col similar to '[0-9]{11}'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=9e282f6f19ba02cddb2f6da63ab5c890).

Comment: Hi forpas, awesome ! tks.

Comment: i think i heart there was something wrong about speed, when using "multipliers" within RegEx in Firebird. To the point that in FB4 they consider using different RegEx library (Google RE2)

Comment: @Arioch'The As far as I know, that problem had to do with complex patterns that trigger backtracking, that shouldn't be a problem here. BTW: They aren't considering a different library, they already switched in September.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel until FB4 is officially released I still consider it as "considered", because until anchored by release fait accompli it can always be switched back if any unexpected hardship with RE2 surfaces.